# Stuck at boot time in the splash screen prior to gui login dialog

Tags: 10.04, boot

This is an issue I've been facing for a long time. However I am still able to use my ubuntu via recovery mode, where I log-in to the shell, where I type `startx`. Sometimes when i restart, it goes in clean. But most of the time I get hung up with the splash screen.

Wondering if this is an issue with mount: heard that ubuntu will check the hdd once after every 30 mounts. I seem to notice it has not being doing that for a while.

Comment: Can you switch to a terminal pressing CTRA+ALT+F1 when it's hang?. I suspect more of a plymouth issue than mount problem, but it could be a couple of things.

Comment: @javier tried that. Didn't work

Comment: You may want to update your question with other actions you've tried and the results.

Comment: In the Grub menu, if you select the normal install and hit the key E you can edit it. Please edit it and remove the words splash and quiet from the line. Then hit enter to boot it. It should show more info now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Boot in recovery mode**

Try pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> right after you BIOS screen to access the grub menu, there you choose "Recovery mode" this will give you more debug messages. When the recovery menu appears you can "Drop to root shell prompt" and then look at the logfiles in `/var/log` folder, especially dmesg.0 (Kernel debug messages from last boot) this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/479448/ - this is the last 50 lines of `dmesg.0`

Comment: The problem might be in line 36, 37, 38 i would start by starting from a live-cd and choose recovery-mode, then enter a terminal and run: `fsck -c -f /dev/sdb1` Looks like it was hanging for 4min 50sec, does that seem right?

Comment: Think you've to execute what Source Lab has  given a couple of times, and by default make it to substitute yes for each question it asks...

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a technically a 'solution', try booting in from a different Kernel if you have any. I also have this issue but been able to boot from a different Kernel. (Primary Kernel: 2.6.32-25-generic, Secondary: 2.6.32-21-generic -- Secondary Works!)

Answer (score 0):

Glad to know I'm not the only one.  I have gotten this problem a number of times too. No amount of hitting ESC key or any other key combination works. The only way is to do a hard reboot. I've always wondered about it but haven't bothered so much since it still works after the forced reboot.