# First reboot after install and Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't start correctly

Tags: 11.10, boot-failure

[This is what I see:](https://i1239.photobucket.com/albums/ff518/PandaFace623/IMG_20120110_194142.jpg)
[image: img]

Once it gets to this screen it hangs/doesn't go anywhere. It's a 64-bit installation, I'm not sure what to do. I've tried installing various ways but I always get the same results. What other information do you need?

[AMD HD Radeon 6850.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121419&Tpk=asus%206850)

Comment: What video card is it ?

Comment: That looks really good IMO, but plymouth is messed up..

Comment: Please look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2013/stuck-at-boot-time-in-the-splash-screen-prior-to-gui-login-dialog, the most voted answer has an easy way of obtaining more information about what is happening.

Comment: The fact that there is a pointer there... looks like ligthgdm is loaded but can't draw itself.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. For some reason the install wasn't quite working while downloading updates via wifi. Once I had plugged in the ethernet cable and installed ubuntu this way it installed correctly and booted correctly. Your links lead me to this resolution, so thanks!